# Woocommerce - Variation Swatches for WooCommerce Plugin - REST API for the attribute terms custom field?

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, php-curl

I've been using this plugin for a little bit and it's **perfect** for what i need. The unfortunate thing is however that i'm looking to build the attribute colours programatically. Because of that i'm having issues assigning the **colour** hex code for the swatches.

The only way i've been able to successfully do this is by doing the following:

- Use Rest API to create the attribute colour if it doesn't exist
- Use Rest API to retrieve the attribute and it's fields after being created
- CURL using the information retrieved in order to adjust the attribute term in the table

While this works per se it's not exactly an elegant solution. I could also use mysql as well to do the same, however i don't like the idea of having a remote database connection for this to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than go ahead with the curl idea, i decided to be incredibly secure about my mysql connection.

For anyone who's curious, the table you need to edit is wp_termmeta

```
insert into wp_termmeta (term_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ("<your_created_attributes_id>", "<colour_taxonomy_name>", "<hex_value_for_colour>");
```